# Generating Regular Expression Parsing

Tags: regex

I need to convert the four lines below into a single regular expression.

```
piece_id="E00401007758725D"
PieceID = E00401007758725D 
Piece=E00401007758725D
piece E00401007758725D
```

I've tried the following:

```
[pP]iece[_]*?[iI]*[dD]* ?[=]* ?"?(?<PieceID>[A-Z0-9]{16}"?)
```

But the output I get looks like `E00401007758725D"`

I followed this [regex](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result) link for checking my Expression.

Comment: ITs working fine here https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/13 .What output did you expect?

Comment: @vks but am getting error from above link

Comment: The link is working.Newaz what your expected output?

Comment: But it doesn't meet above four conditions.

Comment: What is your expected output?can you add that in your question????????????????????///

Comment: The sample you provided is *almost* working, though.

Comment: @vks, he wants `E00401007758725D` instead of `E00401007758725D"`.

Comment: but it fails in first condition getting output like `E00401007758725D"` last character i want to eliminate.

Comment: @ikegami Ha Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to capture the `"`, move `"?` out of the capture.

```
[pP]iece[_]*?[iI]*[dD]* ?[=]* ?"?(?<PieceID>[A-Z0-9]{16})"?
```

[Tested](https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/15)

---

That said, ending with something optional is useless. Also, you have unneeded square brackets, and those stars are suboptimal.  Fixed:

```
[pP]iece(?:_?[iI][dD])?\s*(?:=\s*)?"?(?<PieceID>[A-Z0-9]{16})
```

[Tested](https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/17)

Comment: suggested regex fail for **first** condition remaining works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This expression matches all your sample lines

**Named group**

```
.*[=\ ]\"?(?<pieceId>E.*)\"?
```

**Anonymous group**

```
.*[=\ ]\"?(E.*)\"?
```